# Protractor Typescript error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Tags: typescript, protractor, pageobjects

I am trying to write a login test in Protractor with Typescript.In the page objects I have defined the elements and I get error when I refer them. I wrote the same test with Javascript and it works fine. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here

login.po.ts file

```
export class LoginPage {
      username = element(by.id('userName'));
      password = element(by.id('password'));
      loginbtn = element(by.id('login'));
      loginmsg = element(by.id('login-message'));
}
```

```
import { browser } from "protractor";
import {LoginPage} from '../PageObjects/login.po';

describe('Login', function () {
let loginpg: LoginPage;
  beforeEach(() => {
    let loginpg = new LoginPage();
});

it('should show incorrect credentials error', async () => {
  browser.get("https://example.com/");
  loginpg.username.sendKeys("test@test.com");
  loginpg.password.sendKeys("fsdf");
  loginpg.loginbtn.click();
  expect(loginpg.loginmsg.toEqual('Incorrect username or password'));
})
});
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Comment: Which line produces that error? (please update the question)

Comment: it doesn't say the line number

Comment: What doesn't? Which tool is reporting the error? What is transpiling the typescript code?

Comment: I'm using visual studio code

Comment: have u tried `let loginpg = new LoginPage();` placing just right after import statement and see if it solves the problem?

Comment: @domlas this fixed the problem. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to assign the value instead of the declare new variable in the `beforeEach` function.

```
describe('Login', function () {
  let loginpg: LoginPage; // --> declare
  beforeEach(() => {
    loginpg = new LoginPage(); // --> assign
  });
  //...
});
```

You have to invoke the `getText` method to get a text of the element.
Also, you missed the `)`.

and if you disabled control flow, you have to add `await` for each command.

**SOLUTION:**

```
describe('Login', function () {
  let loginpg: LoginPage;
  beforeEach(() => {
    loginpg = new LoginPage();
  });

  it('should show incorrect credentials error', async () => {
    await browser.get("https://example.com/");
    await loginpg.username.sendKeys("test@test.com");
    await loginpg.password.sendKeys("fsdf");
    await loginpg.loginbtn.click();

    expect(await loginpg.loginmsg.getText()).toEqual('Incorrect username or password'));
  });
});
```